# litespeed detected as not running

Tags: web, litespeed

i have installed open lite speed web server on my own virtual server.

[image: image shows lite speed is enabled]

lite speed is enabled and have installed the plugin for direct admin.
but when i open the plugin page, it says that lite speed is not running.
i have tried restarting open lite speed but nothing is changed.
[image: lite speed is not running]
[image: litespeed configure]

i'm not a server expert and i wish you can help me fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check first you are talking about OpenLiteSpeed, not LiteSpeed (Enterprise).
As mentioned in "[Switching Between OLS and LSWS on DirectAdmin](https://openlitespeed.org/kb/switching-between-ols-and-lsws-on-directadmin/)":

> On DirectAdmin, you can either run LiteSpeed Enterprise, or OpenLiteSpeed, but you cannot run both at the same time.

Then double-check your [configuration files](https://openlitespeed.org/kb/directadmin-configuration-files/) and [reload process](https://openlitespeed.org/kb/reload-openlitespeed-automatically-with-directadmin/), assuming your Apache `.htaccess` is set.

Confirm that OpenLiteSpeed is [actively running](https://openlitespeed.org/kb/install-from-binary/):

```bash
sudo /usr/local/lsws/bin/lswsctrl status
# Or try to restart it
sudo /usr/local/lsws/bin/lswsctrl restart
```

Make sure the configuration files are correctly set up and not empty:

```bash
cat /usr/local/lsws/conf/httpd_config.conf
```

Look for error messages that might indicate the problem:

```bash
cat /usr/local/lsws/logs/error.log
```

Verify if OpenLiteSpeed is listening on the default HTTP/HTTPS ports (80/443):

```bash
sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 'OpenLiteSpeed'
```

Comment: hi
sudo /usr/local/lsws/bin/lswsctrl status 
""[ERROR] litespeed is not running.""

sudo /usr/local/lsws/bin/lswsctrl restart
""[OK] litespeed: pid=1022430.""

cat /usr/local/lsws/conf/httpd_config.conf
""cat: /usr/local/lsws/conf/httpd_config.conf: Permission denied""

cat /usr/local/lsws/logs/error.log
""cat: /usr/local/lsws/logs/error.log: No such file or directory""

sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 'OpenLiteSpeed'
""nothing....""

Comment: sudo service lsws status       works

Comment: @sajad Yes, depending on how it has been installed, you might need to look for those `lsws` folders.